# 2 layouts In One Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Its Possible That I Can Create 2 OnCreateViews In One Fragment ? i have 2 layouts  in my app activity_notice.xml when press a button the another layouts appears activity_main.xml
and the first Layout will be gone

Comment: NO. A fragment can only have **1** `onCreateView()` event. But nothing stops you from putting **2** fragments in the container Activity. Then you will have **2** `onCreateView()` events. *For what is worth* (I still have to understand **WHY** do you need **2** `onCreateView()` events!!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is only one `onCreateView()` event. If you want 2 views in 1 fragment and one of them is gone when you perform some action then you will have to make two layouts in single fragment layout. At a time 1 is `gone` and other 1 is `visible` and you perform event then visible that layout that you want to show and hide other layout.